# TCPDF margins on different page by auto page break

Tags: php, tcpdf

https://ibb.co/qYH0x20

I'm using TCPDF for label PDF on my project.

I set custom footer function. In footer function, there are different margins for second page.
I'm writing text by MultiCell method. But on the project image,

$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, $txt, 1, 'L', 0, 1, '', '', true, 0, true);

// This code is in the Extended footer method.
// $t2 = is page front or back

```
if ($t2 == 2) { $this->SetMargins(2, 1, 7, true); } else { $this->SetMargins(7, 1, 2, true); }
```

Where is the problem??